# Can't get Selected Item Index in custom ArrayAdapter on my ListView

Tags: java, android, selecteditem

I have problem with my Android project, because I can't get selected item index from my List with my own ArrayAdapter. I've tried few examples from tutorials but they don't work. What is the solution?

## Adapter

```
public class myProductAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<myProductsGroup> {

    private List<myProductsGroup> productList;
    private Context context;

    public myProductAdapter(List<myProductsGroup> productList, Context ctx) {
        super(ctx, R.layout.list_products_row, productList);
        this.productList = productList;
        this.context = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
    return productList.size();
    }

    /*
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int position = Integer.parseInt((String) v.getTag());

        OrderFirstGridPage.setSelectedItem(position);             
    }
    */

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_products_row, parent, false);
        }
            TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            tv.setTag(""+position);
            TextView distView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            distView.setTag(""+position);
            tv.setText("aa");
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

## In activity

```
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
lv.setAdapter(new myProductAdapter(setupArrayProductList((ArrayList<myProduct>) ProductList), OrderFirstGridPage.this));
lv.setSelector(R.drawable.selector_for_position_list);
```

Comment: try this http://www.androidhub4you.com/2013/02/muftitouch-listview-multi-click.html

Comment: it helps but when I implement onClick in Adapter my List can't underline me selected item; I decided to try another way and Sharifur Rahman example work correctly. Anyway thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to use this line of code:

```
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    lv.setAdapter(new myProductAdapter(setupArrayProductList((ArrayList<myProduct>) ProductList), OrderFirstGridPage.this));
    lv.setSelector(R.drawable.selector_for_position_list);      

 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                                            @Override
                                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                                    View view, int position, long id) {
                                                Log.d("My POSITION",""+position);

                                            }
                                        });
```

Hope you will get the exact position from selected listview. If you get any problem, please inform me. Hope this will works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement AdapterView.OnItemClickListener: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html

```
public abstract void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
```

There, you'll get the index of each item.

You just have to set that listener to your list:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(yourListener);
```